# Combine multiple match regular expression into one and get the matching ones

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a list of regular expressions:

```
suresnes|suresne|surenes|surene
pommier|pommiers
^musique$
^(faq|aide)$
^(file )?loss( )?less$
paris
faq                              <<< this match twice
```

My use case is that each pattern which got a match display a link to my user,
so I can have multiple pattern matching.

I test thoses patterns against a simple string of text "live in paris" / "faq" / "pom"...

The simple way to do it is to loop over all the patterns with a `preg_match`, but I'm will do that a lot on a **performance critical page**, so **this look bad to me**.

Here is what I have tried: combining all thoses expressions into one with group names:

```
preg_match("@(?P<group1>^(faq|aide|todo|paris)$)|(?P<group2>(paris)$)@im", "paris", $groups);
```

As you can see, each pattern is grouped: `(?P<GROUPNAME>PATTERN)` and they are all separated by a pipe `|`.

The result is not what I expect, as only the first group matching is returned. Look like when a match occurs the parsing is stopped.

What I want is the list of all the matching groups. `preg_match_all` does not help neither.

Thanks!

Comment: "*What I want is the list of all the matching groups.*" `preg_match_all` gives you the list of capturing groups for each match.

Comment: I have tried and only the first one is return with a match.

Comment: `$groups[0]` should contain an array equivalent to the list of matches. `$groups['group1']` will contain a list of the same length with the matches of the 1st group. Same for the group2. Tested it, it works. Also, if you're concerned about performance, check [atomic groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

Comment: Damien is right, I don't see any simple way to do this using `preg_match_all` since it will return match only for first matching group.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about:

```
preg_match("@(?=(?P<group1>^(faq|aide|todo|paris)$))(?=(?P<group2>(paris)$))@im", "paris", $groups);
print_r($groups);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [group1] => paris
    [1] => paris
    [2] => paris
    [group2] => paris
    [3] => paris
    [4] => paris
)
```

The `(?= )` is called [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

**Explanation of the regex:**

```
(?=                                     # start lookahead
    (?P<group1>                         # start named group group1
        ^                               # start of string
            (                           # start catpure group #1
                faq|aide|todo|paris     # match any of faq, aide, todo or paris
            )                           # end capture group #1
        $                               # end of string
    )                                   # end of named group group1
)                                       # end of lookahead
(?=                                     # start lookahead
    (?P<group2>                         # start named group group2
            (                           # start catpure group #2
            paris                       # paris
        )                               # end capture group #2
        $                               # end of string
    )                                   # end of named group group2
)                                       # end of lookahead
```

Comment: Look likes it works! Can you explain this syntax? There is no pipe anymore, and I do not know what `?=()`do... Thx!

Comment: @Damien: I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
#/ define input string
$str_1 = "{STRING HERE}";

#/ Define regex array
$reg_arr = array(
'suresnes|suresne|surenes|surene',
'pommier|pommiers',
'^musique$',
'^(faq|aide)$',
'^(file )?loss( )?less$',
'paris',
'faq'
);

#/ define a callback function to process Regex array
function cb_reg($reg_t)
{
    global $str_1;
    if(preg_match("/{$reg_t}/ims", $str_1, $matches)){
    return $matches[1]; //replace regex pattern with the result of matching is the key trick here
    //or return $matches[0]; if you dont want to get captured parenthesized subpatterns
    //or you could return an array of both. its up to you how to do it.
    }else{
    return '';
    }
}

#/ Apply array Regex via much faster function (instead of a loop)
$results = array_map('cb_reg', $reg_arr); //returns regex results
$results = array_diff($results, array('')); //remove empty values returned
```

Basically, this is the fastest way I could think of.

1. You can't combine say 100s of Regex into one call, as it would be very complex regex to build and will have several chances to fail matching. This is one of the best way to do it.
2. In my opinion, combining large number of Regex into 1 regex (if possibly achieved) will be slower to execute with `preg_match`, as compared to this approach of `Callback` on `Arrays`. Just remember, the key here is `Callback function on array member values`, which is fastest way to handle array for your and similar situation in `php`.

Also note,
The `callback on Array` is not equal to `looping the Array`. Looping is slower and has an **n** from algorithm analysis. But callback on array elements is internal and is very fast as compared.

Comment: This is running all the regexp on all the character of the input string, this is fast and this is working (I have an implementation like this) but I was asking for a way to avoid this. I'm wondering how (if this is possible) to combine thoses patterns into one.

Comment: This is the fastest way I could think of. 

Also,
1) You cant combine say 100s of Regex into one call, as it would be very complex regex to build and few chances to fail matching. This is one of the best way to do it.

2) In my opinion, combining many Regex into 1 regex (if possibly achieved) will be slower to execute with preg_match, as compared to this approach.

Comment: Just remember the key here is `Callback function on array`, which is fastest way to handle array for your and similar situation in php.

Comment: You sould add this explanation to your answer, a valid answer can be "This is not possible, just loop over the patterns" but I would like to know why :) Thx!

Comment: actually, 'callback' is not 'looping'! :D Looping is slow and has an "n" from algorithm analysis. But callback on array elements is internal and is very fast as compared.

Comment: so in Algorithm Analysis, the loop will be "n" statements. but the callback operation will be just "1" statement (i.e. the cost of algorithm).

Comment: Done. Added the explanation to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all of your regexes with "|" in between them.   Then apply this: http://www.rexegg.com/regex-optimizations.html, which will optimize it, collapse common expressions, etc.